# Can I create an orphaned tag using Rugged or another Ruby library?

Tags: ruby, git, tags, rugged

I am trying to emulate the following in Ruby:
    object=$1
    tag_name=$2
    message=$3
    user_name=`git config user.name`
    user_email=`git config user.email`
    date=`date +%s`

```
tag="object ${object}
type commit
tag ${tag_name}
tagger ${user_name} <${user_email}> ${date} +0000

${message}"

echo "${tag}" | git mktag
```

I have tried the following using Rugged:
    repo = Rugged::Repository.new(@full_path)
    tag_collection = Rugged::TagCollection.new(repo)
    annotated_tag_sha = tag_collection.create(tag_name, sha, {:message => msg, :time => Time.now})
    repo.close

However the two are not equivalent. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I did get it working locally using:

```
repo = Rugged::Config.global
type = "commit"
tagname = "v99.99.2"
username = repo["user.name"]
email = repo["user.email"]
message = "this is the message for the annotated tag"
tag_contents = "object f849f9e28c7f36a826d4b451efb16516c0c3acc2\ntype #    {type}\ntag #{tagname}\ntagger #{username} <#{email}> #{Time.new.to_i}     +0000\n\n#{message}"
executecommand = "printf \"#{tag_contents}\" | git mktag"
Open3.popen3(executecommand) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
exit_stats = wait_thr.value
errors = stderr.readlines
puts "Errors are #{errors}"
unless exit_stats.success?
  raise Exception, 'There was an error encountered'
end
signature_file_sha = stdout.readline.chomp
puts "signature sha is #{signature_file_sha}"
```

end

using git 1.9 but it is throwing an error now in git 2.0.4 unable to verify object with id

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can:

```
# Get the repo
repo = Rugged::Repository.open("...")

# Lookup the target object
target = repo.lookup("$object")

# Create the tag annotation object
repo.tags.create_annotation("$tag_name", target, {
  tagger: {
    name: "$user_name"
    email: "$user_email",
    time: Date.parse("$date")
  },
  message: "$message"
})
```

I did not test this, but this should give you at least enough pointers on how to do this with rugged.

Comment: Thanks Arthur. Can you make any suggestions as to why the additional code in my first comment doesn't work with Git 2.0.4?

Comment: No idea. Maybe something changed between git 1.9 and 2.0.4, but I really doubt that is the case. Are you sure there's nothing else that is different?

Also, did you try the suggested solution for rugged?

Comment: I was attempting to run the code through an ide which was working from a non git directory. Running the code file from the command line solved the issue. Thanks again Arthur.